Using Xaml Island in Winform to open a new WPF Window
I have a fairly large WinForm app which I managed to upgrade from .NetFramework to .Net8.  In parallel, I am developing a WPF app in .NET 8 which will eventually replace the WinForm app.  In the meantime I would like to utilize the XAML islands to integrate some of the newer WPF forms in the Winform app.  The strategy works for single user controls that I embed in the host control.  I have one usercontrol (Rep1ViewModel) in the wpf app that opens a new window with a report viewer (ReportViewer).  While the Rep1ViewModel loads in the ElementHost of the Winform app.  Which I click on the event to open a new window, the program crashes on the InitializeComponent() of the new ReportViewer Window.  (The debugger crashes on the first line of the Xaml of the ReportViewer Window ()  Object reference is not set to an instance of the object.
In brief, in the stand alone WPF app, the ReportViewer opens without any problems.  But when called from the embeded wpf usercontrol within the WinForm app, it does not initialize.
Code of the Winform
    Imports System.Windows.Forms.Integration
    Imports BARDV2H.Models.Localdbc
    Imports BARDV2H.Repo
    Imports Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

    Public Class WPF
        Dim ctrlHost As ElementHost
        Dim wpfAddressCtrl As BARDAppW.Views.Rep1

        Private Sub WPF_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            ctrlHost = New ElementHost()
            ctrlHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ctrlHost)
            wpfAddressCtrl = New BARDAppW.Views.Rep1()
            '  MainA hosts the services
            Dim localRepo = MainA.myhost.Services.GetRequiredService(Of ILocalRepo)
            
            wpfAddressCtrl.DataContext = New BARDAppW.ViewModels.Rep1ViewModel(localRepo)

            wpfAddressCtrl.InitializeComponent()
            ctrlHost.Child = wpfAddressCtrl
        End Sub
    End Class
    

Code of the WPF ViewModel  of the DialogForm (Which loads properly in the WinForm app)
public partial class Rep1ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ILocalRepo _localRepo;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<ProgramCounter> programNames;
    public ObservableCollection<string> reportTypes { get;set; }
              .... Additional properties
    private string repTitlestr = "Year";
   


    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task withData()
    {
        List<ResearchA> Research;
        if (EndNumber > StartNumber)
        {if (!repTitlestr.EndsWith("s"))
            {
                repTitlestr += "s";
            }
        }
        string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.ProcessPath);
        bool bt = (ReqOrApprove == 1);
      
        string reportPath = @"O:\Reports\ReportList.trdp";
      
        if((SearchString??String.Empty)!=String.Empty)
        {
          
            Research = await _localRepo.sel_AppResearchbyKeyWords(SearchString, (YorC==1),StartNumber,  EndNumber, AppOrSubmit, SearchCode ?? "%", SelectedPanel.OldPanelNumber, "Counter", SelectedFundingCategory.id, SelectedResearchTract.Tractid);
        }
        else if (YorC == 0)
        {
            Research = await _localRepo.selResearchbyYear(StartNumber, EndNumber, AppOrSubmit, SearchCode ?? "%", SelectedPanel.OldPanelNumber, "Counter", SelectedFundingCategory.id, SelectedResearchTract.Tractid);
        }
        else
        {
            Research = await _localRepo.selResearchbyCounterRange(StartNumber, EndNumber, AppOrSubmit, SearchCode ?? "%", SelectedPanel.OldPanelNumber, "Counter", SelectedFundingCategory.id, SelectedResearchTract.Tractid);
        }
       // This is the line the programe crashes on.  
        var mypage = new ReportViewer(reportPath, Research, Research,bt, String.Format("BARD Submitted Projects {2} {0} - {1}",StartNumber, EndNumber,repTitlestr) );
        var window = new Window();
        window.Content = mypage;
        window.Show();
    }
   
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task getLists()
    {
        //loads comboboxes on form for various options and works in the WinForm
    }
    
    public Rep1ViewModel(ILocalRepo localRepo)
    {
        _localRepo = localRepo;
    }       
    

Codebehind for the ReportViewer
     public partial class ReportViewer : Page
     {
         public  ReportViewer()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
         }
         public ReportViewer(string reportPath,object ds1, object ds2, bool approved, string RepTitle)
         {
         //The line that crashes the program
             InitializeComponent();

             var reportPackager = new ReportPackager();
             Report report = null;
             using (var sourceStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(reportPath))
             {
                 report = (Report)reportPackager.UnpackageDocument(sourceStream);
             }
            
             var table1 = report.Items.Find("list1", true)[0] as Telerik.Reporting.List;
             table1.DataSource = ds1;
             report.ReportParameters["ReportTitle"].Value = RepTitle;
             report.ReportParameters["BudgetType"].Value = approved;
             var reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
             reportSource.ReportDocument = report;
          
             ReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
             ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
         }

     }


XAML islands is not for hosting WPF components by WinForms app...

So your saying it can't host a wpf window?  If I changed the reportviewer to a usercontrol and opened it in a new winform window with an ElementHost could it work?

ElementHost is not XAML islands.
